# Program breaks after a couple hundred lines have been read

Tags: c, string, malloc, fgets, realloc

I made a scanning function which essentially just scans in the lines of a file into a single `char *` called `buffer`. However, after a couple hundred lines are read, the program just stops working. I just get a program has stopped working pop up window. Assuming I did something wrong with memory allocation, but I am unsure what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *scan_file(FILE *fp);

#define MAX_LINE                200


int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char *contents = scan_file(fp);
    printf("%s\n", contents);
    return 0;
}
// Scan in file into a buffer. Returns a malloc-ed string
char *scan_file(FILE *fp) {

    int buf_len = 1;
    int contents_len = buf_len;

    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_LINE + 1));
    char *contents = malloc(sizeof(char) * (buf_len + 1));
    strcpy(contents, "\0");

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE, fp) != NULL) {
        buf_len = strlen(buffer);
        contents_len += buf_len;
        realloc(contents ,contents_len);
        strcat(contents, buffer);
        strcpy(buffer, "\0");
    }

    free(buffer);
    return contents;
}
```

Comment: `realloc(contents ,contents_len);`  Look up realloc in the manual. It returns a value.

Comment: `realloc(contents ,contents_len);` is also off by 1.  I'd expect `realloc(contents ,contents_len + 1);`   OTOH `sizeof(char) * (MAX_LINE /*+ 1*/)` is sufficient, no need for +1.

Comment: @chux why don't I need to do the `MAX_LINE + 1`? I will have 200 characters I can scan plus 1 for the null terminator?

Comment: Also, this is missing a call to `fopen` ==> `FILE *fp = ("test.txt", "r");`

Comment: @Yuri you already told fgets that you only want MAX_LINE characters including the NULL terminator

Comment: BTW: since you are interested in the *complete* file, you do not need to read lines. And you don't need to *copy* lines. You could read single characters, or buffer-sized chunks instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code fails to use the return value form `realloc()`

Allocation sizes off by 1.

Repeated `strcat()` make for a slow (n*n) solution.

Consider using `size_t` for array sizes vs. `int`.

Rather than call the variable `...len`, consider `...size` to acknowledge  the presence of the final *null character* in a *string*.

```
char *scan_file(FILE *fp) {
    // int buf_len = 1;
    size_t buf_size = 1;

    // int contents_len = buf_len;
    size_t contents_size = buf_size;

    // char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_LINE + 1));
    // fgets(..., MAX_LINE, ...) will only read up to MAX_LINE - 1 characters.
    char *buffer = malloc(MAX_LINE);

    char *contents = malloc(buf_size + 1u);
    if (buffer == NULL || contents == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // strcpy(contents, "\0");
    contents[0] = '\0';

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE, fp) != NULL) {
        // buf_len = strlen(buffer);
        buf_size = strlen(buffer) + 1u;

        // contents_len += buf_len;

        // realloc(contents ,contents_len);
        void *p = realloc(contents ,contents_size + buf_size);
        if (p == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        contents = p;

        // strcat(contents, buffer);
        strcpy(contents + contents_size, buffer);

        // now add
        contents_size += buf_size;

        // Code here not truly needed, yet helps in debugging.
        // strcpy(buffer, "\0");
        buffer[0] = '\0';
    }

    free(buffer);
    return contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- use `realloc()`s return value
- `realloc(NULL, size)` works just like `malloc(size)`; no need to pre-allocate
- avoid excessive copying and `strlen()`
- just put the data where you want it the first (and only) time you touch it.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *scanfile (FILE *fp)
{
size_t size, used;
char *buff = NULL;
int ch;

for (size=used=0;;      ) {
        ch = getc(fp);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        if (used+1 >= size) {
                size_t newsize = used? 2*used: 1024 ;
                char *tmp = realloc(buff, newsize);
                if (!tmp) FAIL();
                else {buff = tmp; size = newsize; }
                }
        buff[used++] = ch;
        }

        /* Nothing read: return NULL */
if (!used) return NULL;
buff[used++] = 0;

/* maybe realloc (shrink) buff here */
return buff;
}
```